# How do I patch values back to an object in Angular 13?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, boolean

I have an issue with **patchValue** and **setValue** in Angular 13.

I have a form I created using formBuilder called *manageUsers*. In it, I have a key called userRoles that contains an *array of booleans*.

The *manageUsers* form contains checkboxes for the user roles. The array of booleans turns those checkboxes into checked/unchecked based on the boolean values.

When you first visit the page, the userRoles array in the *manageUsers* form, by default, look like this...

```
this.manageUsers.value.userRoles = [false, false, false, false, false]
```

When a user *checks* or *unchecks* a checkbox, the form recognizes a change in state and the "Save Changes" button enables. If someone clicks the "Save Changes" button, then the *manageUsers* form gets sent to an endpoint where it is saved in a database.

When you select a user, for example "Anthony", the information for that user checks against a list of 5 user roles that looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "AnalyticalAdmin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "SystemAdministrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "CaseworkSTRTechLeader"
    }
]
```

to see what roles are assigned to Anthony. Let's say "AdminReviewer" is assigned. Then the resulting userRoles array would look like this...

```
this.manageUsers.value.userRoles = [false, false, true, false, false]
```

That means the third checkbox ("AdminReviewer") would be appear checked in the form and the others would not be checked. So let's say then you were to check the second checkbox ("Analyst"). The updated userRoles in the manageUsers form would look like this...

```
this.manageUsers.value.userRoles = [false, true, true, false, false]
```

What I've done is written code to compare that array with the list of 5 roles above.

The resulting array looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    }
]
```

So far so good.

**Here's my problem**...

When I go to patch that array of objects **BACK INTO** the *manageUsers* form, the result looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    true,
    false,
    false
]
```

Angular, for some reason, wants to **add booleans** to make up for the three missing elements. But here's the thing, I **ONLY WANT** the *this.manageUsers.value.userRoles* form object to contain the **two objects**. I don't need the superfluous booleans.

I just want the *this.manageUsers.value.userRoles* object (that I'm sending back to the database) to look like this...

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    }
]
```

**NOT LIKE THIS**...

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    true,
    false,
    false
]
```

I've tried using **BOTH** .patchValue and .setValue methods, but they don't work.

How do I patch an array of objects and tell Angular to **NOT** include booleans for the roles I didn't want to account for?

***UPDATED**...

Here is the code I use set the *userRoles* array...

```
this.manageUsers = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: null,
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      userInitial: ['', Validators.required],
      netUserName: ['', Validators.required],
      workPhone: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9 ]{10}")]],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      userTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      userRoles: new FormArray([], Validators.required),
      incidents: new FormArray([], Validators.required)
    })
```

Then, I created a property called *userRolesArray*...

```
public get userRolesArray() {
    return this.manageUsers.controls.userRoles as FormArray;
  }
```

Then, I created a property called *addCheckboxesToManageUsers()* and call that in the **ngInit()** method.

```
private addCheckboxesToManageUsers(): void {
    this.listOfUserRoles.forEach(() => this.userRolesArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
  }
```

Comment: can you show code of how you are setting and modifying your roles array?  It is hard to know what is going on without it.

Comment: I updated the code above with additional code. Remember, I'm only concerned with how to patch the updated array of objects back into the manageUsers form without it adding extra booleans to it.

Comment: Where is your listOfUserRoles property coming from? wont your foreach never fire because it is always empty? Can you show your html bindings?  Overall if I were you I would not use the formbuilder for the checkboxes and just add checkboxes with a ngfor and bind them with the check events to add them to your user role array

Answer (score 1):

after getting value from `this.manageUsers.value.userRoles` use reducer to remove all `boolean` type of value.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "AdminReviewer"
    },
    true,
    false,
    false
]

const newArr = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (typeof curr !== 'boolean') prev.push(curr);
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(newArr)
```

updated one-liner

```
data.filter(data => typeof data != 'boolean')
```